# Disable one bean discovery in weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

I have a project that I want to deploy on two WebLogic servers. One is using JMS and the other doesn't use that so I want to use WebLogic to disable the discovery of my @MessageDriven bean.

I've already read about `beans.xml` and `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml` but I can't figure out how to use them for this specific purpose, also using them won't be so helpful for me because I want to use the exact same version in both servers but with using Weblogic enable or disable the discovery of that bean.

I'm not familiar with Java EE so any help or hint to read about something would be helpful.

Comment: All WebLogic instances on which you deploy your application should have resources needed by your application (ie JMS)  Now, if you really need to have 2 deployment configurations you can do it using a deployment plan. You deploy your 
 application 2 times : 1 usual deployment targeted on the first server and a second one with a deployment plan to update your application configuration targeted to the second server.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin can I configure my deployment plan to not use JMS? I mean something like ignoring my MessageDrivenBean so I don't need to configure a useless JMS on my second server?

Comment: yes if your MDB is declared in ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml files.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin excuse me for asking too much but how can I achieve this? I've already searched about weblogic-ejb-jar.xml but can't find anything that could help me.

Comment: the idea is to remove your MDB declaration from weblogic deployment descriptors using a deployment plan.